# Retrieve LDAP information offline

Tags: c#, ldap

I have the simple code below

```
using (DirectoryEntry deLocal = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + domainName+"/"+userName))
{
   foreach (string propName in  deLocal.Properties.PropertyNames)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(propName+":"+Convert.ToString(deLocal.Properties[propName].Value));
   }
}
```

And similarly using `LDAP://`.

I want to be able to access the same, or most of, the same data when the computer is not inside the domain, like a laptop a user takes home from the office. When the laptop is in the domain/network/vpn it has access to all of the information from the LDAP server.

Is there a similar way to access the while the laptop is on another network, logged in as the domain/user?

Comment: Not sure to understand what you need. You need user information or the whole directory informations?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the [Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services (AD LDS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa705886%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

This is a subset of the full-blown AD - but basically works much the same way. It's installable on local machines, down to Windows XP, and can be run as a service and thus it can also be turned off when not needed.

Microsoft also has tools to synchronize between a central AD instance, and a local AD LDS setup.